# Error al desplegar un pipeline de dotnet en Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, pipeline

Estoy tratando de desplegar una aplicación hecha en `C#` con `dotnet` desde `Jenkins`, este es mi pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'git@github.com:soportecentaurus/integrador.git'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build') {
            
            steps {
                //sh 'dotnet restore /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Integrador/integrador_prod/src'
                sh 'dotnet build'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Deploy') {
            
            steps {
                // Agrega aquí los comandos para el despliegue
               
                sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Integrador/integrador_prod/src && dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish'
                
               
            }
        }
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                sh 'dotnet test'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                // Agrega aquí los comandos para la publicación
                  //sh 'dotnet nuget push ./path/to/library.dll --source https://url-to-nuget-repo --api-key your-api-key'
                sh 'scp -i /var/lib/jenkins/keys/integrador.pem -r ./publish/* jenkins@107.22.243.138:/opt/integrador'
                sh 'cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Integrador/integrador_prod/src/publish/appsettings.Development.json cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Integrador/integrador_prod/src/publish/appsettings.Production.json'
                sh 'dotnet integrador.api.dll'
                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
+ dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.4.8+6918b863a for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```